# Google Maps API : Get Land type

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I'm having square set of coordinates (left top and right bottom).

I also investigated, that older version of API had `type` like `natural_features`. Now, in V3, doesn't have it.
I want to scan area where is no water, forest and another types of land, where human can't build.

How can i get information about land type?

Comment: You need to use the Places API or [Places Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places), it still has info about place types, see https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types which includes `natural_feature` (although I don't see forest, water etc, but maybe this is all-encompassing)

Comment: @duncan, ok, thanks for reply. I will try out that one. And about forest, water - it was just as example :)